# Loopback: Query by Subdocument Id in Loopback

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loopbackjs

I would like to have a document which has sub document, which looks like below:

```
course: {
   id,
   name,
   sections: {
    section: {
      id,
      name
    }
  }
}
```

How do i create this model in Loopback?
I don't want to create a separate model for section, because i want to model it as a sub document.

Also, provide some information about how to get the sub document from the sub document id.

for example: if i want to find details about section with id = 2, it should not take in details about course and provide details just about the section.

Comment: Everything you want to do is straightforward with Loopback, under the conditions that you create a `section` model and setup a few relations between `course` and `section`. Care to detail more why you don't want to create a separate model ?

Comment: @Overdrivr, because then i would have to query the database multiple times to get the sections associated with the course. The over-head to join the database would be high, to avoid that, I am trying to model section as a subdocument.

Comment: That's very, very early "optimization" don't you think ? And if really later in your application you find the database to be the bottleneck, you will always be able to use smarter strategies like distributing/sharding it

Comment: This is something that i am trying to test the performance using this architecture. This is something which is done as a proof of concept. So please provide some way of creating document with such structure.

Comment: Ok, provided an answer. I would be interested on the results of your benchmarks using MongoDB as backend, if you're willing to share them. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [embedded models](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Embedded-models-and-relations.html).

Here is an example `Course.json` config using `Course` `embedsMany` `Section` relation.

Please note that you don't need to declare the `Section` model anywhere else, since it's embedded inside `Course`.

```
{
  "name": "Course",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "emails": {
      "type": "embedsMany",
      "model": "Section",
      "property": "name",
      "options": {
        "forceId": true,
      }
    }
 ...
}
```

Then, to add emails address to a course programmatically, first find an instance of a course then use its generated email property. Again, [this is documented](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Embedded-models-and-relations.html#helper-methods-1)

```
var id = 0;
Course.findById(id, function(err,course) {
  course.emails.add({name: 'foo@bar.com'}, function(err, ..) {
  //...
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide information about how to create and query the model? 
Suppose I have created a course model using: Course.create(courseObj);
Now, how can I create an email address and add to the course?